# Parsing JSON using Java JSONParser

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonparser

I'm trying to parse a JSON File. I wrote the code below to parse using Java JSONParser:

```
    public static void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject jsonObj) {
            for (Object keyObj : jsonObj.keySet()) {
                String key = (String) keyObj;
                Object valObj = jsonObj.get(key);
                if (valObj instanceof JSONObject) {
                    parseJSONResponse((JSONObject) valObj);
                } else if (valObj instanceof JSONArray) {
                    System.err.println("ARRAY");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(key + " -> " + valObj.toString());
                }
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\extract.json");
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                Object obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) (obj);
                parseJSONResponse(object);
            } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

It returns me a response like this:

```
description -> For testing purposes only
indexUpdatedAt -> 1420751985
flags -> ["default","restorable","restorePossibleForType"]
data -> [["row-mfpy.gr8q.cpii","00000000-0000"],["00009","9BCA"]]
columns -> [{"renderTypeName":"meta_data","fieldName":":sid"},{"renderTypeName":"meta_data"}]
```

I need to further parse "flags", "data" & "columns" to retrieve the values individually. How can i modify my "parseJSONResponse" method to achieve this?

Comment: In else if condition, that is when valObj instanceof jsonarray, for each jsonobject in that json array , call parseJsonResponse method again..

Comment: For example, for (int i=0; i < valObj.length(); i++) { valObj.getJSONObject(i); }